# How do I turn django's settings object into a dict?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-settings

What I have:

```
from django.conf import settings

def settings_to_dict(settings)
    cfg = {
        'BOTO3_ACCESS_KEY': settings.BOTO3_ACCESS_KEY,
        'BOTO3_SECRET_KEY': settings.BOTO3_SECRET_KEY,
        # repeat ad nauseum
    }
    return cfg

instance = SomeClassInstantiatedWithADict(**settings_to_dict(settings))
```

What I'd like (using Django 1.11):

```
from django.conf import settings

instance = SomeClassInstantiatedWithADict(**settings.to_dict())
```

I've tried:

```
from django.conf import settings

instance = SomeClassInstantiatedWithADict(**settings.__dict__)
```

which is close, but `__dict__` only gets a small subset of the settings, which I assume are hard coded ones as opposed to added attributes. Thanks for any help!

Comment: What is the use case for this? `settings.__dict__` only contains settings that have already been accessed

Comment: Well, there is dictionnaries in your settings and maybe other types of data structures, what do you plan on doing with them ?

Comment: What Django version?

Comment: @IainShelvington The use case is that I have a controller class (wrapping the AWS API to spin instances up and down, attach EFS drives, etc) that I originally developed within a Flask app. To __init__() the class, I simply pass flask's app.config object (which behaves as a dict), picking up on the BOTO3_* config variables and other keys required.

I'm now building the wider app in django, but want to continue using the same classes for django and for various associated flask micro services, with minimal modification of the class.

Comment: @wim, updated question (Django 1.11)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use the following code:

```
from django.conf import settings
instance = settings.__dict__['_wrapped'].__dict__
```

Then you will have the whole settings dict in `instance` as dictionary.

Comment: Thanks @akimul, accepted answer as this is working nicely, plus you included the complete import and assignment.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you really need ALL the settings?

Why not use a little helper, you pass in all the settings u need and a default value. Like this you always get a dict with the settings you actually need, even if they aren't configured.

```
    def build_settings_dict(attrs=[{'name': 'DEBUG', 'default': False},]):
        settings_dict = {}
        for attr in attrs:
            logger.info(attr)
            try:
                s = getattr(settings, attr['name'], attr['default'])
            except Exception as e:
                logger.warning("Error: %s", e)
            else:
                settings_dict[attr['name']] = s
        return settings_dict


    default_settings = build_settings_dict([
       {'name': 'DEBUG', 'default': True},
       {'name': 'USE_I18N', 'default': True},
       {'name': 'USE_L10N', 'default': False},
    ])
```

Comment: Thanks, dirkbo. Not strictly an answer to the question, but I like it when SO members try to help you become better :). As I said in the comments on the original post, this was done as part of a quick shift flask>django, to avoid refactoring a bunch of submodules. Naturally, as a responsible dev, I've long since gone back and cleaned up the submodules to use the right settings.

Answer (score 0):

This turns the entire settings object into a dictionary:

```
In [12]: settings_dict = {}

In [13]: for st in dir(settings):
    ...:     if st.startswith('_'):
    ...:         continue
    ...:     settings_dict[st] = getattr(settings, st)
    ...:
    ...:

In [14]: settings_dict
```

This is very exhaustive and it contains all possible attributes of settings.

`dir()` is a Python builtin. Read about it [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#dir)

Answer (score 0):

Check `settings.__dict__['_wrapped'].__dict__` in your shell. It seems there is everything inside. Not sure however if it's the right way to access this.

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> from django.conf import settings
>>> settings_dict = vars(settings._wrapped)
>>> print(settings_dict)
{'ABSOLUTE_URL_OVERRIDES': {}, 'ADMINS': [], 'ALLOWED_HOSTS': ['127.0.0.1', 'localhost', 'www.tetricoins.com', 'api.tetricoins.com'], 'APPEND_SLASH': True, ...
```